# Android Facebook SDK Logging out & Clearing the Current User Session

Tags: android

After you logout using ParseUser.logout, when the come back to login in the app still remembers the previous user and tries to login automatically.

I tried using the ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(), but it's deprecated I think.
So, how do i Logout my user.

This is what i have tried so far:

```
ParseFacebookUtils.getSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
ParseUser.logOut();
```

Login Code:

```
 ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            if (user == null) //Pressed Cancel Button
            {
                Log.d("FaceBookParse -> ", "OnCancel");

            } else if (user.isNew()) //New User
            {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                getUserInfo();
                Log.d("FaceBookParse -> ", "OnNewUser");

            } else //Old User
            {
                Log.d("FaceBookParse -> ", "OnOldUser");

            }
        }
    });
```

OnClick:

```
 ItemClickSupport.addTo(mRecyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(
            new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this,"Settings",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position - 1);
                            Drawer.closeDrawers();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position - 1);
                            Drawer.closeDrawers();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position - 1);
                            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                            Drawer.closeDrawers();
                            startActivity(new Intent(Dashboard.this, LaunchPage.class));
                            break;

                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: show code how you are logging in

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Put this method in your logout button's onlick listener.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Comment: It comes back as an old user, if i try to login again

Comment: did above method works for you? show your logout.onclick method

Comment: if you try to login again is it asking you for email and password or not?